# disable existing checkboxes of the form

Tags: javascript, checkbox, for-loop

I have check boxes I want to have a for loop that it will disable any check box that is in the form
i don't want to give array names to them cause maybe sometimes I have to insert another checkboxes I want to automatically disable the new one too by this for loop

is it possible writing an if statement that when the type is checkbox disable it?
if it is impossible please tell me another solutions
Thanks in Advance

```
function useraccess()
{
     document.getElementById('frag3').disabled=true;                 
     document.getElementById('stream4').disabled=true;
     document.getElementById('stream5').disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: `useraccess` means you will disable them cause the user is not authorized? I don't think that's a good idea. Make sure you have server-side validation though.

Comment: In PHP I got session if the user is not admin I call the useraccess

Comment: Here's a tip, before  sending the page to the browser, do not render these checkboxes 'coz there are tools which can manipulate DOM elements, a hacker can easily enable your checkboxes. What I meant in server-side validation is, when the user submit the form, double check if the user has the right to send the data produced by those checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't got your mention about double check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```